# How can I combine the object with tape?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I have problem :)

I'm working on a project which is basic electric motor model and ı almost finish the project but ı noticed the interetesting thing which is ı dont know 
How can I combine the object with tape?

This is example:[image]

This is my model: 
[image]

As you see tapes are broken in the my render:) I need help .

Comment: The gray band? Shrinkwrap modifier maybe? Or duplicate the battery and cut it at the shape of the tape.

Comment: Yes grey band. Unfortunately shrinkwrap didn't work.I think cut is a little bit hard for me, even so thanks for advice :)

Comment: why don't you simply model it?

Comment: I thought if I came this stage, I could.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create the tape (from a plane) approximating the shape of the battery and wire.
   Go into sideview and extrude the plane. (the more accurate this is done the better will be the result)
   [image: approximated tape mesh]
2. Subdivide it, to get higher resolution (the more verticies it has the better will be the result). You can use Catmull-Clark or Simple both work.
   [image: subdidived tape mesh]
3. Duplicate the object you want to get wrapped (select objects and press ctr + d,the location,rotation and scale has to be the same as the original)
   [image: duplicated battery and wire]
4. Join the duplicated objects to one Mesh and hide the original objects (select the objects you want to hide and press h, select the objects you want to join and press ctrl+j)
   [image: dublicated battery and wire joined]
5. Select the tape and add the shrinkwrap modifier

   - select the object you want to wrap around as target (battery and wire)
   - set the mode to Project
   - set the axis to x and z (this depends on the orientation of your scene, ether x and
     z or y and z)
   - check at direction both Positive and Negative

[image: tape with shrinkwrap modifier]

6. Add a solidify modifier, to add thickness to the tape
   [image: tape with solidify modifier]
7. Hide (not vieible in viewport and render) the copy and unhide the original objects.
   And add smooth shading.
   [image]

You can increase the subdivision level afterwards to get more or less detail.

Comment: Thank you,ıts works :)